# Сколько человек сможет одновременно смотреть видео в 720p при канале в 100Мбит?

Tags: видео

На хосте лежит видео. Ширина канала 100 мегабит. Сколько пользователей сможет  одновременно смотреть видео в качестве 720p? Как рассчитать?

Comment: Поток у видео какой?

Comment: Если битовый поток видео (+аудио, +оверхед) больше 100Mbit/s, то ни одного, а если почти 0 (статическая картинка без звука), то всё население Земли.

Answer (score 1):

Как посчитать к сожалению не подскажу, но могу сказать, что у нас при трансляции видео с собственного сервера (скорость интернета 100 мегабит), начинались проблемы при просмотре видео одновременно 5ю - 6ю пользователями. (5-6 человек и трансляция начинала притормаживать)

Comment: 5-6 человек или 1000?

Comment: 5-6 человек. Трансляцию делали с собственного сервера.  Интернет провайдер - Фрегат. Скорость 100 мегабит.

Comment: да тут не трансляция а просто просмотр видео.